# $f,g$ be two analytic function on unit disc st that $f\cdot g=0$.Does it imply$ f=0$or$ g=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f,g$ be two analytic function defined in a unit disc of the comlex plane such that $f\cdot g=0$. Does it imply either $f=0$ or $g=0$? If it is not true the give an counter example or any hints.

Comment: Do you know a result about analytic functions with zeros with an accumulation point?

Comment: Is * the ordinary product or a convolution product?

Comment: it is ordinry product

Comment: sir,I know this,but if $f*g=0$ only on unit disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ = unit disk

$Z_f = \{ z \in G: f(z) = 0\}$ and $Z_g = \{z \in G: g(z) = 0\}$.

if   $f$ has countably many zeros. $ \implies g$ has uncountably many zeros since $f(z)g(z)
=0  \forall z \in$ $G$

around any point in $G$, there exists infinitely many zeros of $g(z)$, 
i.e. $Z_g$ has a limit point in G $\implies g(z) = 0$.

similarly if   $g$ has countably many zeros$ \implies  f(z) = 0$.

if Both $f$ and $g$ have uncountably many zeros then both $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ will 
be equal to $0$

Comment: I have one question,$f$ analytic on unit disc means $f$ is analytic in some annular region containing the unit disc

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak  look at this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticFunction.html